# Issue with typing '/' symbol to an input field with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, selenium-chromedriver, geb

```
Geb: org.gebish:geb-spock:2.2
Groovy: 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.2
Webdriver: 76.0.3809.12
Chrome: 76.0.3809.132
```

Recently I faced really weird Selenium behavior:

A test types the value to an input field, which is supposed to represent the path to some file. Test input data is taken from a `json` file and comes to the test as `Map<String, Object>`:

```
{
      "name": "Preview_Geometry_out",
      "value": "geometry/previewGeometry.stl",
}
```

The problem is that the `/` symbol disappears from the typed value, so input value is displayed as: "geometrypreviewGeometry.stl"

I added some debug to the method where the value is set:

```
 private Closure processParameterData = { Navigator el, String newValue ->
    if (newValue) {
        println "Typing: " + newValue
        el.value(newValue)
        println "Actual value: " + el.value()
        return newValue
    }
    el.value()
}
```

The output is:

```
    Typing: geometry/previewGeometry.stl
    Actual value: geometrypreviewGeometry.stl
```

But when I record a video, I **do see** that typed value hadn't contained slashes when was typed in, so it is not a kind of field's value post-processing by js etc.

I tried this with plain selenium API, replacing this: `el.value(newValue)` with: `el.singleElement().sendKeys(newValue)`. Result is the same.

I cannot reproduce this manually. 
I cannot reproduce this when the test is running in Chrome on my Win10 laptop. But when tests are running remotely via Jenkins on CentOS (testing the same application which is deployed on the same host), the issue appears at several places on my project. No any specific js functions or CSS styles on those inputs.

Any thoughts? 
Thanks in advance.

---

**UPD:** After some debugging I found out that the issue occurs only if there is a scroll bar displayed on the form: is such a case the form goes down at the moment when (and instead of) typing the '/' symbol. Escaping it didn't help, as well as pausing and sleeping. 
The only workaround I have for now is:

```
if (newValue.contains('/')) {
    js.exec(el.singleElement(), "arguments[0].value = '$newValue'")
} else {
    el.value(newValue)
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is related to [Chromedriver issue #894](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=894), I don't know. This and similar reports I googled indicate that it might be related to the locale used on your system. Maybe you can play around with that and see if the system and browser locales match, if it works if everything is set to English etc. As `sendKeys` emulated keyboard activity, the keyboard locale settings might be the root cause. This is nothing more than an educated guess, though.